# Is there a way to configure some parameters in a system before opening a structure in VESTA?

Tags: vesta

I have several structures to visualize and print out. I previously opened them using terminal commands in Linux:

```
~/VESTA-gtk3/VESTA POSCAR
```

But I need to set up bonds, overall appearance, and atom color, every time. Is there a way to do this setup before opening a structure in VESTA?